# Missing output file from webpack and node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to setup a node.js server. Currently when I run npm start with the current webpack.config.js everything loads. When I run node server, the index.js is missing.

```
webpack.config.js
   var config = {
   context: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
   entry: './js/main.js',
   output: {
      path: __dirname + '/src/',
      filename: 'index.js',
   },
   devServer: {
      inline: true,
      port: 8080
   },
   module: {
      loaders: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}

module.exports = config;
```

Here is the html, left out things not needed to see.

```
<html lang="en">

  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --content-base src --hot",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "history": "^1.17.0",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "http": "0.0.0",
    "react-socket-io": "^0.2.4",
    "socket.io": "^2.0.3",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1"
  }
}
```

I'm fairly new to node.js and webpack so I'm not exactly sure why index.js is getting outputted when I run npm start but not when I run node server. I can upload the server.js but it follows a very basic template.

Edit: It seems I got it working, I need to run webpack dev server as well as the node.js server on different ports. Follow up question, is it possible to change this to only run the node server and still have everything work?

Comment: When using the dev server, no files are written to disk. it's all served from memory

Comment: You sure can. Checkout https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run `webpack --config path/to/webpack.config.js` to generate `index.js` in the file system before starting node server.

You can add `build` command to your `package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --content-base src --hot",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  ...
}
```

and then before starting node server run `npm run build`

Comment: Worked perfect thank you. I had to remove devServer from webpack.config.js, is this appropriate since I am using node.js?

Comment: my pleasure :) You probably need devServer object to keep your development (npm start) to work. I'm not using webpack-dev-server, so not really sure. Does build break if you don't remove devServer?

Comment: You won't need webpack-dev-server when you are using node server. But the changes you will make in client js file wont be reflected as the build is older. You will have to rebuild using npm run build and then rerun the nodejs server. There is alternative to this trivial thing. Webpack-dev- mideware to rescue.  See @jakewies comment link to get going.